# Record dynamic memory allocation usage

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Recently I am involved in a C project on a micro controller.
There are many malloc() or calloc() in our project.
  My question is about is it possible to use an array or another dynamic allocate array in runtime to record the allocated memory existing duration, i.e the time from the memory has been allocated till it has been freed , and where it was freed. 
  Thanks for any help.

Comment: The memory manager in a C program is *you*. It is up to you to keep track of the amount of memory allocated, if that is a requirement. You can use a global for this purpose.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - that's the theory but, like free-threaded code, the practice of tracking down memory leaks takes an unbelievable amount of debugging time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this "by hand", first, you need to replace all instances of malloc, calloc and free with your own functions (eg _malloc, _calloc and _free). For production, these can be defined as the original functions thereby carrying no overhead but for debug code, you have them call your own functions:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _malloc(s) myMalloc(s,__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define _calloc(b,n) myCalloc (b,n,__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define _free(p) myFree (p, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#else
#define _malloc malloc   //  If not debugging, just use the default
#define _calloc calloc
#define _free   free
#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG // Or whatever your compiler preset is
void *myMalloc (size_t sz, const char *pszFile, unsigned long line)
{
    //  Save the details in a table with the time
    ...
    return malloc (sz);
}
void myFree (void *ptr, const char *pszFile, unsigned long line)
{
    //  Process the table, do time calculations etc and then remove it
    free (ptr);
}
#endif
```

This is the only way to really overload malloc and free. The constants **FILE** and **LINE** will tell you where the memory was allocated and freed. NB. If you are going to allocate table space in myMalloc, use malloc, not _malloc or you may get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using glibc, you can use its `mtrace` function and tool to trace all memory allocations and releases, without changes to your source code.

> The  mtrace() function installs hook functions for the memory-allocation functions (malloc(3), realloc(3) memalign(3), free(3)).  These hook functions record tracing information
>          about memory allocation and deallocation.  The tracing information can be used to discover memory leaks and attempts to free nonallocated memory in a program.
>
> When  mtrace()  is  called,  it  checks the value of the environment variable MALLOC_TRACE, which should contain the pathname of a file in which the tracing information is to be
>          recorded.  If the pathname is successfully opened, it is truncated to zero length.

It supplies a command line tool to interpret the trace file, also named `mtrace`.

reference:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/mtrace

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mtrace

Comment: As far as I know, the mtrace() is included in glibc, and when the program execute the mtrace() data will be written to the file which the "MALLOC_TRACE" point to. But my project environment is a micro controller which has no os. Is it possible fo me to use mtrace()? By the way, we use ARM toolchain in this project.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use a library like [this one](https://github.com/fredericgermain/LeakTracer) but this actually depends on type of the development environment for a particular controller. It could be an advanced one, with all possible bells and wistles available for a developer, and likewise could be pretty limited in capabilities so you might end with a custom solution like the one suggested by @Mike above.